# Multiplicative Identity analog for absolute value

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a standard name for the function:
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if |x|≤1;}\\
1/x & \text{if |x|>1;}\\
\end{cases}
$$
And is there a potential application of this function? All I can think of is that it will be able to sort ratios according to the "magnitude" of the ratio.

I would see it as a "absolute value" function that deals with the multiplicative identity, since the modulus function can be defined as such:
$$
|x| = 
\begin{cases}
0-x & \text{if x<0;}\\
x & \text{if x≥0;}\\
\end{cases}
$$

And $0$ is the additive identity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the idea of having such $f$ as an absolute value. An absolute value "with respect to multiplicative identity" sounds like a function that maps $e^x \mapsto e^{|x|}$.

Comment: I don't know about function names, but a construction similar to that is sometimes useful in the localization of roots of polynomials...

Comment: for positive $x$ you can use $$\mathrm e^{|\log{x}|}$$ if you need to include negative value into consideration, then $$\operatorname{sgn}(x)\mathrm e^{|\log|x||} $$ so it is just a use of absolute value function in the composition with other

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is there a function".

Comment: "has a standardised name been assigned to the function"

Comment: @Ilya your function should be posted as an answer, looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Definition_and_properties it's interesting to see some dualities