# Does the geometric analogy of absolute function have a name?

Tags: functions, terminology

While writing a function (of a computer program), I needed a mathematical function of variable *x* such that *f*(*x*) = *x* for |*x*| > 1, and 1/*x* otherwise (I know, *f*(0) is undefined).

As the absolute function, |*x*| = *x* for *x* > 0, and -*x* otherwise, I wondered if my function *f* has a standard name in mathematics. Has it?

Comment: Well, $f(x)=e^{|\log x|}$

Comment: No, no standard name.

Comment: The same question has been asked here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106639/multiplicative-identity-analog-for-absolute-value?rq=1, but it doesn't have any answer.